# Fedex Shipping Weight and Value is not setting while creating order programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm trying to create orders programmatically using the FedEx shipping method. other methods are working fine. when I'm setting the FedEx getting the error like please specify the shipping method.
After debugging I come to know weight and value are zero but I mentioned product weight and value.

Code :

Create.php

```
<?php
namespace yourmodule\namespace\Helper;
class Create extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
     /**
    * @param Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
    * @param Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    * @param Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    * @param Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey $formkey,
    * @param Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
    * @param Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    * @param Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $orderService,
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formkey,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $orderService,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate $shippingRate
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_formkey = $formkey;
        $this->quote = $quote;
        $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->orderService = $orderService;
        $this->shippingRate = $shippingRate;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Create Order On Your Store
     * 
     * @param array $orderData
     * @return array
     * 
    */
    public function createMageOrder($orderData) {
        $store=$this->_storeManager->getStore();
        $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer=$this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);// load customet by email address
        if(!$customer->getEntityId()){
            //If not avilable then create this customer 
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                    ->setStore($store)
                    ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
                    ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
                    ->setEmail($orderData['email']) 
                    ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
            $customer->save();
        }
        $quote=$this->quote->create(); //Create object of quote
        $quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote
        // if you have allready buyer id then you can load customer directly 
        $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer

        //add items in quote
        foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
            $product=$this->_product->load($item['product_id']);
            //$product->setPrice($item['price']);
             $product->setWeight(20);
            $quote->addProduct(
                $product,
                intval($item['qty'])
            );
        }

        //Set Address to quote
        $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);

        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method

        $shippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();
        
        /*$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                        ->collectShippingRates()
                        ->setShippingMethod('fedex_FEDEX_GROUND'); //shipping method
                        
        */
        //$this->shippingRate
          //  ->setCode('fedex_FEDEX_GROUND');
            //->getPrice(1);
        //$shippingAddress = $cart->getShippingAddress();
        //@todo set in order data
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
            ->collectShippingRates()
            ->setShippingMethod('fedex_FEDEX_GROUND'); //shipping method
        //$quote->getShippingAddress()->addShippingRate($this->shippingRate);       
        $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method
        $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory
        $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready

        // Set Sales Order Payment
        $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);

        // Collect Totals & Save Quote
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
        
        // Create Order From Quote
        $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);

        $order->setEmailSent(0);
        $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
        if($order->getEntityId()){
            $result['order_id']= $order->getRealOrderId();
        }else{
            $result=['error'=>1,'msg'=>'Your custom message'];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

FedEx debug log :

```
array (
  'request' => 
  array (
    'WebAuthenticationDetail' => 
    array (
      'UserCredential' => 
      array (
        'Key' => '****',
        'Password' => '****',
      ),
    ),
    'ClientDetail' => 
    array (
      'AccountNumber' => 'XXXXXX',
      'MeterNumber' => '****',
    ),
    'Version' => 
    array (
      'ServiceId' => 'crs',
      'Major' => '10',
      'Intermediate' => '0',
      'Minor' => '0',
    ),
    'RequestedShipment' => 
    array (
      'DropoffType' => 'REGULAR_PICKUP',
      'ShipTimestamp' => '2017-06-27T06:09:23+00:00',
      'PackagingType' => 'YOUR_PACKAGING',
      'TotalInsuredValue' => 
      array (
        'Amount' => 0,
        'Currency' => 'USD',
      ),
      'Shipper' => 
      array (
        'Address' => 
        array (
          'PostalCode' => '90034',
          'CountryCode' => 'US',
        ),
      ),
      'Recipient' => 
      array (
        'Address' => 
        array (
          'PostalCode' => '11701',
          'CountryCode' => 'US',
          'Residential' => false,
          'City' => 'Ave Forest Hills',
        ),
      ),
      'ShippingChargesPayment' => 
      array (
        'PaymentType' => 'SENDER',
        'Payor' => 
        array (
          'AccountNumber' => 'XXXXX',
          'CountryCode' => 'US',
        ),
      ),
      'CustomsClearanceDetail' => 
      array (
        'CustomsValue' => 
        array (
          'Amount' => 0,
          'Currency' => 'USD',
        ),
      ),
      'RateRequestTypes' => 'LIST',
      'PackageCount' => '1',
      'PackageDetail' => 'INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES',
      'RequestedPackageLineItems' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'Weight' => 
          array (
            'Value' => 0.0,
            'Units' => 'LB',
          ),
          'GroupPackageCount' => 1,
        ),
      ),
      'ServiceType' => 'SMART_POST',
      'SmartPostDetail' => 
      array (
        'Indicia' => 'PRESORTED_STANDARD',
        'HubId' => NULL,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'result' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'HighestSeverity' => 'ERROR',
     'Notifications' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'Severity' => 'ERROR',
       'Source' => 'crs',
       'Code' => '809',
       'Message' => 'Package 1 - Weight is missing or invalid. ',
       'LocalizedMessage' => 'Package 1 - Weight is missing or invalid. ',
       'MessageParameters' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'Id' => 'PACKAGE_INDEX',
         'Value' => '1',
      )),
    )),
     'Version' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'ServiceId' => 'crs',
       'Major' => 10,
       'Intermediate' => 0,
       'Minor' => 0,
    )),
  )),
) {"is_exception":false} []
```

OrderData :

```
$orderData = [
     'email'        => 'ram10test@gmail.com', //buyer email id
     'shipping_address' =>[
            'firstname'    => 'Ramki ', //address Details
            'lastname'     => 'ram',
                    'street' => '10119 Ascan Ave Forest Hills',
                    'city' => 'Ave Forest Hills',
            'country_id' => 'US',
            'region' => '43',
            'postcode' => '11701',
            'telephone' => 'XXXX',
            'fax' => '32423',
            'save_in_address_book' => 1
                 ],
   'items'=> [ //array of product which order you want to create
              ['product_id'=>'2','qty'=>1]
            ]
];
```

Please assist me on this I tried flat rate and free shipping it's working but FedEx it's not working.

Comment: you have set weight in a product  which is perfect but you have not set any package weight of quote.Due to this Fedex Returns an invalid package weight of quote .so kindly set weight before calling a " ->collectShippingRates() " function and re-check

Comment: have you checked product weight value was saved in database ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to catalog, select the product and add weight in the weight attribute field.